# How to get acces to the PromiseResult (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

this is my code:

```
    const sendBoardId = async boardId => {
    let result;
    try {
        result = await axios.get(`${fetchConfig.prefix}/game/get_board_by_id`, {
            params: {
                boardId,
            },
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    console.log('board:', result.data);
    if (result.data == null || result.data.length == 0 || result.data == undefined) {
        const BoardData = [];
        return BoardData;
    }
    return result.data;
};

const Board = sendBoardId(1);

console.log('aaa', Board);

export { Board };
```

In the "aaa" console log I keep getting promise, and only in the promise result I got what I needed,
I want to export the promise result and not all the promise it self.
How should I do it?

Comment: `const Board = await sendBoardId(1);`

Comment: hi, It won't work because it says await needs to be inside of an async function

Comment: Follow, Answer provided below

Answer (score 0):

To use Promise

```
const sendBoardId = async (boardId) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let result;
    try {
      result = await axios.get(`${fetchConfig.prefix}/game/get_board_by_id`, {
        params: {
          boardId,
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      reject(e);
    }
    console.log("board:", result.data);
    if (
      result.data === null ||
      result.data.length === 0 ||
      result.data === undefined
    ) {
      resolve([]);
    }
    resolve(result.data);
  });

const Board = sendBoardId; // UseLess

console.log("aaa", Board);

export { Board }; // Better to direct export sendBoardId
```

And use:

```
import {Board} from "...........";

const xyz = async() =>{
const data = await Board(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I left this by trying something really different.
I tried it before your editing and it didn't work, this may work now after your changes.